# Prolog program to create a list with first duplicate elements

Tags: prolog, run-length-encoding

I need to implement this function:

```
cod_first(X, L, Lrem, Lfront).
```

`Lfront` contains all the copies of `X` that are at the beginning of `L`, including `X`; `Lrem` is the list of the rest of the elements.

I've tried to implement it using append but I'm quite new in Prolog and I'm a bit lost.

The expected output for the program is something like this:

```
?- cod_first(1, [1, 1, 2, 3], Lrem, Lfront) 
Lrem = [2, 3],
Lfront = [1, 1, 1];
false.

?- cod_first(1, [2, 3, 4], Lrem, Lfront)
Lrem = [2, 3, 4],
Lfront = [1];
false.
```

Update: I've found this function that packs the same elements into a list:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [[X]]).
pack([X, X| L], [[X| Xs]| R]) :-
    pack([X| L], [Xs| R]).
pack([X, Y| L], [[X]| R]) :-
    X \= Y,
    pack([Y| L], R).
```

I think this function could be adaptable to the one I'm looking for, any help?

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode [RLE](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Prolog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's check the code you found! I will test it by considering *all* lists, starting with the shortest one:

```
?- N=N, length(Xs,N), pack(Xs, Xss).
   N = 0, Xs = [], Xss = []
;  N = 1, Xs = [_A], Xss = [[_A]]
;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A]]
;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A,_A]]
;  N = 4, Xs = [_A,_A,_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A,_A,_A]]
;  ... .
```

So, according to this query, your code only works for lists where all elements are the same. In fact, the goal `X \= Y` is responsible for this. Better express inequality with `dif(X, Y)`. With this little change we get:

```
 ?- N=N, length(Xs,N), pack(Xs, Xss).
    N = 0, Xs = [], Xss = []
 ;  N = 1, Xs = [_A], Xss = [[_A]]
 ;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A]]
 ;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_B], Xss = [[_A],[_B]], dif(_A,_B)
 ;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A,_A]]
 ;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_A,_B], Xss = [[_A,_A],[_B]], dif(_A,_B)
 ;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_B], Xss = [[_A],[_B,_B]],  dif(_A,_B)
 ;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_C], Xss = [[_A],[_B],[_C]], dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C)
 ;  N = 4, Xs = [_A,_A,_A,_A], Xss = [[_A,_A,_A,_A]]
 ;  ... .
```

Now we get really all solutions.  Let's consider the two answers for `N = 2`. The first says that for `Xs`'s elements being all equal, `Xss` contains just one element. The second says that when `Xs`'s elements are different, they show in separate elements of `Xss`. Note the `dif(_A,_B)` which ensures that only terms that are different are chosen.

However, you are only interested in a single such split:

```
cod_first(X, [], [], [X]).
cod_first(X, [X|Es], Lrem, [X|Xs]) :-
   cod_first(X, Es, Lrem, Xs).
cod_first(X, [E|Es], [E|Es], [X]) :-
   dif(X,E).

?- N=N, length(Xs, N), cod_first(X, Xs, Lrem, Lfront).
   N = 0, Xs = [], Lrem = [], Lfront = [X]
;  N = 1, Xs = [X], Lrem = [], Lfront = [X,X]
;  N = 1, Xs = [_A], Lrem = [_A], Lfront = [X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 2, Xs = [X,X], Lrem = [], Lfront = [X,X,X]
;  N = 2, Xs = [X,_A], Lrem = [_A], Lfront = [X,X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 2, Xs = [_A,_B], Lrem = [_A,_B], Lfront = [X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 3, Xs = [X,X,X], Lrem = [], Lfront = [X,X,X,X]
;  N = 3, Xs = [X,X,_A], Lrem = [_A], Lfront = [X,X,X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 3, Xs = [X,_A,_B], Lrem = [_A,_B], Lfront = [X,X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_C], Lrem = [_A,_B,_C], Lfront = [X], dif(_A,X)
;  N = 4, Xs = [X,X,X,X], Lrem = [], Lfront = [X,X,X,X,X]
;  ... .
```

Here is another version which I prefer using `library(reif)` available
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).

```
cod_first2(X, Es, Lrem, [X|Xs]) :-
   cod_first2i(Es, X, Xs, Lrem).

cod_first2i([], _, [], []).
cod_first2i([E|Es], X, Xs0, Ys) :-
   if_( E = X
      , ( Xs0 = [X|Xs], cod_first2i(Es, X, Xs, Ys) )
      , ( Xs0 = [], Ys = [E|Es] )
      ).
```

This is much more efficient, but gives exactly the same answers.